# Computing parametric integral (Gauss-Cosh-Cosh)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, gaussian-integral

Let $s > 0, t \in \mathbf{R}$, and define

\begin{align}
I (s, t) = \int_{x \in \mathbf{R}} \exp \left( -\frac{sx^2}{2} \right) \cdot \frac{\cosh (tx) }{ \cosh (x) } dx.
\end{align}

I am seeking a moderately-concrete analytic form for $I$, e.g. if a pure analytic form is not available (which I consider fairly likely), then a rapidly-convergent infinite sum of analytic terms would do just fine.

Some things which I have tried (without success):

- I have had a go at this integral with a pretty standard rectangular contour. Going upwards in the complex plane causes the Gaussian term to grow quickly, and so I am not sure how productive this approach is. Perhaps a different contour would be more forgiving.
- I also tried some formal calculations where I took partial derivatives of $I$ with respect to $(s, t)$, which led me to the PDE $\partial_t^2 I + 2 \partial_s I = 0$, which looks to me like a backwards heat equation. I can compute that $I(s, 0) = \sqrt{2 \pi / s}$, but I suspect that this is not enough to determine a solution (noting that $s$ is the `time' variable of the PDE).
- I represented $1/\cosh(x)$ as a scale mixture of Gaussians (i.e. $1/\cosh(x) \propto \int_{t > 0} p(t) \cdot \mathcal{N} (x | 0, t) dt$) and then exchanged the order of integration. This gives rise to an integral with respect to $t$ which is at least as challenging as the original form, as the particular $p(t)$ is not so nice.

Any suggestions for other approaches I could try? (or, indeed, a full solution)

Comment: Search 'Mordell integral.'  One of the first papers I googled, 'The Mordell integral, quantum modular forms, and mock Jacobi forms,' by B. Chern and R. Rhoades has your form in the first line of the document, although the parameter before the $x^2$ looks pure imaginary, not real.